# Populate excel data on html page

Tags: html, excel

I'm newbie to the tech world. I need some information on how to do this.

1) We have data in excel sheet(where actively data changes are done like edit, delete, input data )

2) We have html page where when we enter login of a employee all the information about that employee should be shown on webpage with the information from above excel sheet.

I don't know php, .net etc. Simply I can do html and a little java script.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot directly get excel data to display on a html page. You would have to use something like MySQL and PHP, or if you simply need the excel sheet online, try something like google docs

Comment: I didn't  tried anything because I don't know from where to start. So how can I related MySQL and HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read you problem, and here is my help.

First you have to know that excel files are difficult to use in other programs.
They are maybe APIs out there like google docs or microsoft office that can help you extract data from an excel file but this is not easy and not a long term solution.

I assume you are using excel because it is an easy way to input data and see that data. You should consider creating a database with access, that has a similar interface. In the options you should chose sql as format. You should learn a bit about sql.

Once you have a sql file that contains all the data that previously was in your excel file, go learn the basics of a server side language like node(node is javascript with server functionality) for instance.

Then write a html template that works for a employee.

When server is requested information from an employee you populate that html template with data found in the sql database. To find data in sql it is very easy once you know the basics of sql.

Forget the excel and enter new data exclusively in the sql database file(s).
You can do that with access or other tools.

Comment: A common solution to deal with data from Excel Files is to convert them to CSV (manually or automatically, depending on the case).

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, will think about this. So there is no way to do this using xml or any other tool?

Comment: "Walle Cyril", could you please help me with the sample code?

Comment: if you need further help you can ask another question, if you want to chat I invite you in this [chatroom](http://dystroy.org/miaou/84?General_Programming)